# Is there a way to store lower 64 bits of multiplication int64_t * int64_t in C?

Tags: c, overflow, multiplication

This is the function I need to implement using C.
Note that it is not allowed to use gcc builtins.
Thank you for any help!

'''

```
imull(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t *res) {
    // a * b = ..64bits..|..64bits..
    //                       *res
    *res = a * b;
}
```

'''

Comment: The l.s. 64 bits of a 128-bit value need a `uint64_t` variable. And anyway there is no problem with a 64*64 bit multiplication when the product *is* also 64 bits. BTW you can check whether there will be an overflow by first dividing one operand into the maximum value representable, to see if the quotient is less than the other operand.

Comment: Apart from that, you can make your own bigint by using unions and 32-bit parts, and doing "long-hand" multiplication yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an `int64_t` is multiplied by an `int64_t`, the true arithmetic result is a 128-bit number with its sign bit at bit 127. The low 64 bits do not contain a sign bit. Therefore, the low 64 bits of the multiplication ought to be returned in a `uint64_t`, not an `int64_t`, and this can be accomplished with:

```
imull(int64_t a, int64_t b, uint64_t *res)
{
    *res = (uint64_t) a * (uint64_t) b;
}
```

(The casts avoid overflow in the multiplication, as unsigned integer arithmetic is defined to wrap, not overflow.)

If the bits must be returned in an `int64_t`, this can be done in a way defined by the C standard using:

```
imull(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t *res)
{
    uint64_t temporary = (uint64_t) a * (uint64_t) b;
    memcpy(res, &temporary, sizeof *res);
}
```

(`memcpy` is declared in `<string.h>`.)

Also note that if the true arithmetic result fits in an `int64_t`, then the `int64_t` returned by the above code will equal the true arithmetic result. (This is a property of the two’s complement representation, which `int64_t` uses.)